# pass http request response to use in others http requests in same thread group

Tags: jmeter, httprequest

I'm new using JMeter and I have this case:

```
Test Plan
  Test Group1
   Http Request 1
   Json Extractor1
   BeanShell Assertion1
   Http Request 2
   Http Request 3
```

And I want to use the response of HTTP req 1(extracted in JSON extractor) in both HTTP request 2 and 3. For request 2 is working fine I just use ${response} and works fine but when I try to user the same variable in request 3 is like is empty is not showing anything.

So I tried to put the BeanShell Assertion and do a var.set or even a set property, but is still not working. It is like the var or property is being set, and I can see them in HTTP req 2 but in HTTP req 3 they are empty.

Is there another way to set the variable or the response of the request 1 to be use in any other requests of the same thread?

Thanks

Comment: I forgot to mention that I tried to look for an answer for this but I could only find about share varibles in the same thread group, and all I tried worked fine from http req 1 to http req 2, but not for getting it in http req 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to amend your test design and make the JSON Extractor a child of the Http Request 1

- Test Plan

  - Test Group1

    - HTTP Request 1

      - JSON Extractor
    - HTTP Request 2
    - HTTP Request 3

If you have JSON Extractor at the same level as HTTP Requests 1-3 it's being executed after **every** of them so it tries to extract the value from HTTP Request 2 response, doesn't find it and the variable gets empty or default value.

The same applies to the Beanshell Assertion.

More information: [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules)

With regards to using Beanshell in general [it's not very recommended](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting), since JMeter 3.1 you should be using [JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Comment: Thank you that worked perfect, and I didn't even had to use the Beanshell Assertion anymore, just access the variable from the Json extractor.
Thanks again.